# How to find representative cycles of Vietoris Rips persistence diagrams

Tags: software, topological-data-analysis

I am using the Python package [giotto-tda](https://giotto-ai.github.io/gtda-docs/0.5.1/modules/generated/homology/gtda.homology.VietorisRipsPersistence.html#gtda.homology.VietorisRipsPersistence) to calculate [persistence diagrams](https://giotto-ai.github.io/gtda-docs/0.5.1/theory/glossary.html#persistence-diagram) of certain 3d point clouds using a [Vietoris Rips filtration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietoris-Rips_Filtration) and euclidean distance. I am especially working with 1 and 2-d persistence, i.e. cycles and voids.

**Question:** Do anyone know if there's a way to get representatives of a homology class from these algorithms, either using giotto-tda, ripser or something else?

**In short**: Given an algorithm like Ripser and a tool like giotto-tda:s VietorisRipsPersistence, I can get a list of (birth, death) pairs for a point cloud, but essentially I have no idea what points in the cloud contributed to the cycle class of a pair. I want a way to pick a set of representatives, perhaps for say a minimum cycle.

I assume one could sort of back-track through the calculations with the boundary maps, but I have no idea how to get at this from within giotto-tda. If I could somehow get the equivalent of a dendrogram for 2d-homology with all the vertices at the bottom, that would do, but I am not sure this is possible.

*If this sounds too software specific, please either excuse me; refer me to somewhere else or take it as a more general question: I am not bound to use giotto-tda for this, but I would prefer it as well as a smooth integration with Python.*

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling with the same issue. So far, what I have found is that [Ripser can give you representative co-cycles](https://ripser.scikit-tda.org/en/latest/notebooks/Representative%20Cocycles.html). Ironically, as far as I can tell from the documentation and the code, giotto-tda is based on Ripser but apparently was hard-coded not to include that option.

Also, I've found [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8544243/) on finding a good representative using optimisation.